# jQuery - find object in array of objects based on partial match of one element

Tags: jquery, grep, find

I have an array of objects, with one element being comma separated list of values.
When a new object is created, I want to check if there is an object in the array that, among other things, might contain one or more this comma separated values.

```
// Test array
var mappings= [
        { "id": 1, "ip": "1.2.3.4", "pain_in_the": "1, 2, 3"  },
        { "id": 2, "ip": "5.6.7.8", "pain_in_the": "4, 6, 8" },
        { "id": 3, "ip": "3.4.5.6", "pain_in_the": "5, 7, 9" }
    ];
var id = $('#tbID').val();  // Lets' say 4
var ip = $('#tbIP').val();  // Let's say "6.7.8.9"
var pit = $('#tbPIT').val();  // This can be "10, 11, 2", with "2" already in first object
```

When I check, I need to have the first object returned since its pain_in_the field contains "2".

Not sure what to put in ???? placeholder, assuming I am using the right APIs:

```
// Check
var result = mappings.find(item => item.id=== id || item.ip=== ip ||  ????? );

var resultAarray = $.grep(mappings, function (item, i) {
    return (item.id== id || item.ip== ip || ????);
});
```

Also, if value of "pit" variable is "10, 2, 8"; with 2 and 8 being in two separate objects in the array, would both objects be returned?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a comma-separated list instead of an array?

Comment: This is just reading from a textarea control where user enters a set if values, separated by comma.

Comment: I mean in the `mappings` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the comma-separated list to an array using `.split()`, then use `includes()` to test if the value is in the array.

```js
var mappings= [
    { "id": 1, "ip": "1.2.3.4", "pain_in_the": "1, 2, 3"  },
    { "id": 2, "ip": "5.6.7.8", "pain_in_the": "4, 6, 8" },
    { "id": 3, "ip": "3.4.5.6", "pain_in_the": "5, 7, 9" }
];

var id = Number("4");
var ip = "6.7.8.9";
var pit = "10, 11, 2";

let pit_arr = pit.split(", ");

var result = mappings.find(item => 
    item.id === id || 
    item.ip === ip || 
    pit_arr.some(i => item.pain_in_the.split(", ").includes(i))
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, Will give it a try. Would this return two objects if pit = "10, 2, 6", with 2 and 6 belonging to first and second objects in the array?

Comment: No. `find()` only returns the first matching object. If you want to get all matches, use `filter()`.

Comment: just replace find with filter? result=mapping.fliter(item => ... || pit_arr.some (...)?

Comment: Yes. That will return an array of all matches. It's like `$.grep()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can regex any entries delimited with `,` :

```js
var mappings= [
    { "id": 1, "ip": "1.2.3.4", "pain_in_the": "1, 2, 3"  },
    { "id": 2, "ip": "5.6.7.8", "pain_in_the": "4, 6, 8" },
    { "id": 3, "ip": "3.4.5.6", "pain_in_the": "5, 7, 9" }
];

var id = Number("4");
var ip = "6.7.8.9";
var pit = "10, 11, 2";

const regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + pit.replaceAll(', ', '|') + ')\\b');

const result = mappings.filter(item => 
    item.id === id || 
    item.ip === ip || 
    regex.test(item.pain_in_the)
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add a bit more items and it becomes faster than splitting the string into an array for each item:

```
` Cycles: 1000000 / Chrome/117
-------------------------------------------------
Alexander   1.0x  |  364  369  370  378  378  388
Barmar      1.8x  |  661  667  671  676  687  707
-------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```html
<script benchmark="1000000">

var mappings= [
    { "id": 1, "ip": "1.2.3.4", "pain_in_the": "1, 2, 3"  },
    { "id": 2, "ip": "5.6.7.8", "pain_in_the": "4, 6, 8" },
    { "id": 3, "ip": "3.4.5.6", "pain_in_the": "5, 7, 2" },
    { "id": 1, "ip": "1.2.3.4", "pain_in_the": "1, 2, 3" },
    { "id": 2, "ip": "5.6.7.8", "pain_in_the": "4, 6, 8" },
    { "id": 3, "ip": "3.4.5.6", "pain_in_the": "5, 7, 2" },
    { "id": 1, "ip": "1.2.3.4", "pain_in_the": "1, 2, 3" },
    { "id": 2, "ip": "5.6.7.8", "pain_in_the": "4, 6, 8" },
    { "id": 3, "ip": "3.4.5.6", "pain_in_the": "5, 7, 2" },
    { "id": 2, "ip": "5.6.7.8", "pain_in_the": "4, 6, 8" },
];

var id = Number("4");
var ip = "6.7.8.9";
var pit = "10, 11, 2";

// @benchmark Barmar

let pit_arr = pit.split(", ");

mappings.filter(item => 
    item.id === id || 
    item.ip === ip || 
    pit_arr.some(i => item.pain_in_the.split(", ").includes(i))
);

// @benchmark Alexander
const regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + pit.replaceAll(', ', '|') + ')\\b');

mappings.filter(item => 
    item.id === id || 
    item.ip === ip || 
    regex.test(item.pain_in_the)
);
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```